# Blender's 3D model shows distorted image

Tags: modeling, objects, camera, image, color

Thank you all for your support. I am from an international school and the Blender in our PC Lab is having an issue when students use Blender for their 3D modelling class. I have gotten word from their homeroom teacher that the Blender error occurs when you right click on an object and when rotating the camera. The 3D object will 'create' another flat planed image/object. (Sorry about the bad description of the error)

Blender Error Image:
[image]
[image]

Comment: That looks like some kind of OpenGL error or some other GPU compatibility issue. Check to verify GPU compatibility, and make sure all GPU drivers are up to date.

Comment: Christopher, thanks for the advice. I will check if the GPU drivers are updated or not. we have just upgraded the pc's in our labs to dell's optiplex 3080. previously on the old HP AIO desktops there were no issues with blender.

Comment: Hi all,

I have already update the GPU drivers for the pc and the same error still occurs. It only happens when you move the camera around the object.

Comment: Hi - don't know you're still having this problem but some users experiencing a similar phenomenon have had success by deleting the %appdata%\Blender Foundation\ folder. See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251952/75504