# I'm having trouble with gizmo lines getting glicht: rotating, moving or scaling

Tags: opengl, gizmo

System:
Windows 10 64 bit
CPU
I5-3470
GPU
GT 630

Processor and Graphics do not matter because the same thing happens on different Graphics and Processor

I found a fix but on ubunto I have windows

[image]

Comment: I fixed it by just removing the blender foundation folder from %appdata%

Comment: Another user reported on Blender chat that fully removing and reinstalling Blender fixed the same or very similar issue.

Comment: Another user on Blender chat reported deleting %appdata%\Blender Foundation\ worked like KALER suggested.