# Random color streaks in Object View

Tags: object-mode

when in Object view random color lines and layers shows up. somtimes it vanishes suddenly sometimes it stays.
is this coz of any lag in processing?

[image: Sample of the random colours. its different everytime]

Comment: This looks to me like some kind of glitch, possibly with hardware. Could you give us more details? What version of Blender are you using? I can see this is not a default startup scene as it contains an empty. Is anything attached to that empty? Does this happen in any Blender scene randomly or is it triggered by doing certain things? How can we recreate the steps you took to get this? If it's just one file, could you share the file?

Comment: He's using Blender 3.0.1.  (Bottom-right corner of window.) That looks as if it could be a graphics driver problem to me although I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: I've seen something like this before - some users experiencing a similar phenomenon have had success by deleting the %appdata%\Blender Foundation\ folder. See here -  https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251952/75504