# Why is the color of my object glitched

Tags: materials

[image][image]

Im new to blender, and every time I add I material for a color and this happens and I don't know what to do.

Comment: That is definitely not normal behavior. Could you perhaps post some info about your hardware (specifically CPU and GPU) as well which OS you're using?

Comment: Also, some users experiencing a similar phenomenon have had success by deleting the %appdata%\Blender Foundation\ folder. See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/251952/75504

Answer (score 0):

Off hand nothing clear comes to mind, but there must be a reason.  If this were to happen to me I would try the different renders {Eevee, Workbench, Cycles} to see how it might affect the appearance and present any clues.  I'd also check the Shader editor as it appears that nodes are enabled (but not shown) and I'd check the geometry node editor to see if some had been set up (maybe you were following some tutorial earlier and are now not thinking about geometry nodes (which can affect shaders)?).

I'd also suggest simply starting a new project to see if you get the same results - seems like your project is very simple and easy to redo from scratch.  I guess I'd also check the Viewport Shading dropdown, the lighting and the object Viewport display settings, render the object and make more changes to see how it affects the color.

Blender is quite amazing but there are a lot of controls and it can be hard to remember all of the items that can have an impact.  Sometimes you just have to hunt and debug, looking for clues.  Your question is presented in a very simply way (not a lot of data to go on) but if I had this, I'd be looking at those things I suggested.

Good luck!