# Strange Blocks of color in Sculpt Mode

Tags: sculpting

When I enter sculpt mode and hover over an object a strange (mostly red with some pink) block of color will appear in the upper right of the workspace. The color will vary in hue when the curser is moved along the upper portion of any geometry present and disappear altogether when the curser moves to the lower portion of the geometry. The block of color overshadows all other interface graphics within the workspace window, making it impossible to use any tools properly.

Currently running v3.1.2
Utilizing duel Nvidea 1060 cuda for redraw

Comment: That sounds like a graphics driver issue or a bug. If you're sure the drivers are up to date, submit a bug report via Blender's Help > Report a Bug including an image if possible. (Use drag and drop into the report editor to include an image.)

Comment: Without an image, it's hard to tell, but it sounds like something I've encountered before - Some users experiencing a similar phenomenon have had success by deleting the %appdata%\Blender Foundation\ folder. See here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/251952/im-having-trouble-with-gizmo-lines-getting-glicht-rotating-moving-or-scaling